# Difference vector target and genomic target

Tags: pcr

In Pfu turbo DNA Polymerase AD information sheet (and possibly in many other) different amplification targets are divided in Genomic DNA targets, Vector DNA targets and cDNAs. 
What is the difference between the first two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Genomic DNA is a DNA that has whole set of genetic data of an organism. You usually extract it with a whole DNA extraction kit.

Vector DNA is a vector (usually a plasmid, it can also be artificial chromosome,...the type of vector depends on the species and strategy you are using) that has you desired string of DNA in it (for example a gene you want to insert in to a organism) and you are using it to get your recombinant DNA to the organism.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Genomic DNA is usually bigger and more complex than plasmid DNA which is a relatively simple DNA ring of limited size.